# form_set_error not working

Tags: drupal-7

I have the following form functions. My problem is when I submit the form, I don't see the error message (it is highlighted red though). It does log in the watchdog table, so I know it is getting to that point in the code.

```
//Inside hook menu
$items['resume/joblist'] = array(
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array("ac_resume_job_list_form"),
  'access arguments' => array('view joblist'),
  'title' => 'Job List',
  'description' => 'Job List',
);


function ac_resume_job_list_form($form, &$form_state)
{
  $form['display_options'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => 'Display Options',
    '#attributes' => array("style" => "width:250px"),
  );

  $form['display_options']['limit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Limit',
    '#size' => 2,
  );

  $form['display_options']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Change Display',
  );


  return $form;
}


function ac_resume_job_list_form_validate($form, &$form_state)
{
  if ($form_state['values']['limit'] <= 0 || !is_int($form_state['values']['limit']))
  {
    watchdog('ac_resume', 'Display option error'); //THIS SHOWS IN ERROR LOG
    form_set_error('limit', "Limit must be a positive number");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you only need to use the `'display_options][limit'` syntax when the parent element has the [`#tree`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#tree) attribute on it, I've just put your code into a test site and you just need to change the code to use `'limit'` instead:

```
form_set_error('limit', "Limit must be a positive number");
```

That works fine for me.

Comment: It only highlights the field red. It's not showing an error message.

Comment: By any chance are you calling `drupal_get_form` in a template file or theme preprocess function?

Comment: No, it's getting called from hook_menu

Comment: Hmmm interesting. Is the line <?php print $messages; ?> in your theme's `page.tpl.php` file?

Comment: That was missing. I added it and now it is displaying. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that if you have the form element highlighted but the error message not showing up then your custom theme probaly does not contain the $messages variable on that page so it cannot display....

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with: "it is highlighted red though). It does log in the watchdog table, so I know it is getting to that point in the code."

The message is probably there, but your theme/css is hidding it ;-).